# Java deletes my resource files

Tags: java, eclipse, file, delete-file

I use `getClass().getResource()` in my java pong game which I have created. The problem is that during the runtime eclipse works fine... everything is in the project folder, I close eclipse and I see my project, everything is fine. If I run lets say eclipse tomorrow my resource files in the project folder such as image files, sound files get deleted.

What could possibly be wrong ?
Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am saving all my files on the bin folder?

Comment: In you run configuration have you set to clear configuration before launching or clean workspace or any other option like that.

Comment: Is your project folder also your Java Build Path's output folder? Everything in the output folder other than source folders is subject to deletion as needed.

Comment: @wrongAnswer I think that one is fine